# can I make functions with unresolved dependency in C?

Tags: c, inline, extern

what is the **SHORTEST** or **Easiest** way to solve the following dependency problem. Given, I have to keep `xx` in a separate file.

> file1.h

```
    static inline void xx(){
      yy();//yy is not defined in this file but defined in file2.c;
    }
```

> file2.c

```
  #include "file1.h"
  void yy(){
     printf("Hello");
   }

    void main(){
      xx();
    }
```

Compiler error in file1 yy not defined.

Comment: It is actually defined in the same translation unit, it is just not declared prior use.

Comment: Functions (and variables, and types, and structures, etc.) needs to be *declared* before they are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A declaration is required but not a definition:

```
// file1.h

static inline void xx() {
    void yy(); // Just a declaration

    yy(); 
}
```

```
// file2.c

#include "file1.h"
void yy() {
    printf("Hello");
}

int main() { // void main is not legal C
    xx(); // Works fine.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pre-Declare `yy`.

> file1.h
>
> ```
> +++ void yy();
>
>     static inline void xx(){
>       yy();
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Just function declaration prior using will solve the issue.

```
static inline void xx() {
    void yy();
    yy();  // no more yy is not declared
}
```